# Looking for Python API documentation for openstack load balancer component (Octavia)

Tags: python, openstack

I am looking for examples or actual documentation for Train level Openstack Octavia (Load Balancer component) python API.   Everything in the OS project doc site seems to be focused on the CLI.   I would like an example and possible API specification (what to pass in, what to expect out of the functions defined for the OctaviaAPI class in the component.   I have been looking for a few hours with little success.

Comment: Try https://docs.openstack.org/openstacksdk/latest/user/proxies/load_balancer_v2.html. In general, projects' documentation sites don't cover Python bindings, as they are not part of the projects. OpenstackSDK is its own project. I am not the one who downvoted your question, by the way.

Comment: @berndbausch  Thanks for the suggestion,  will check that out.  appreciate the response.

Comment: @berndbausch  that looks to be the info I was looking for.   If you want to put that in an answer I would be happy to take it as the answer.  Also, if you feel there is value in the question please consider voting on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try https://docs.openstack.org/openstacksdk/latest/user/proxies/load_balancer_v2.html. In general, projects' documentation sites don't cover Python bindings, as they are not part of the projects. OpenstackSDK is its own project.

Comment: so the final piece of what I was looking for was a discussion of the members of the connection object.  for other services we had been using client objects associated with their python packages.  of octavia there is no client object.   I just needed to get a connection object instead and use the load_balancer member of that to access the functions of the octavia LoadBalancer class that the link above describes.

Answer (score -1):

Yeah, the client based python binds are being phased out in favor of the openstacksdk. Octavia went straight to using openstacksdk for the python bindings.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30925218)